# How to fit my data to a valid model

Tags: r, modeling, nonlinear-regression

I apologize if this is a repeat question. I would like to show my workflow and ask for specific doubts along the way. This will be a long question. I have some data of plant organ sizes for which I am trying to model the pattern of gene expression of my gene of interest. Let us call the organ: Leaf (whose length has been measured) and the gene: A (whose expression level has been measured).

This is my data :

```
Leaf <- c(45.9,55.2,60.6,62,63.8,64.7,65.3,65.6,68.7,74.9,79.3,79.6,80.2,80.5,80.8,82,85.1,85.9,86.7,88,91.5,91.7,94.4,97.3,111.8,117,117.1,121.7,124.6,132.3,133.7,133.8,134.6,135.4,136,136.9,139,143.4,145.6,146.4,150.4,150.8,152,154.5,155.8,159.5,163.2,164.8,166.4,166.4,169.8,170.7,171.6,174,176.2,177.2,179.5,179.6,184.7,188,190.6,191.9,200,213.9,215.9,224.4,225.2,229,233.4,237,237.5,238.6,241.1,241.3,242.5,242.5,247.9,249.2,249.3,256.8,258.8,258.9,260.9,268.1,268.8,269.7,273.8,274.2,276.3,279.7,280.7,289.6,290.7,292.3,295.4,304.4,308,315.3,316.1,337.7,342.3,344.1,349,349.4,352.6,353.8,354.3,362.8,366.3,370,388.8,390,394.9,398.5,400,401,407.8,410.8,411.4,412.5,415.6,419.5,427.5,430.8,431.3,436.1,452.2,454.3,456.5,456.9,459.1,460,469,490.1,497.3,497.9,518.5,541.5,555.5,560.3,564.2,579.3,585.3,586.8,590.6,603.2,612.4,628.3,633.3,654.8,672.5,676.9,678.5,685.4,686.7,696.8,713.2,713.9,714.3,723.5,727,735.1,750.9,761,764.3,773,832.7,834.5,890.2,898,898.9,911.9,940.7,958.8,964.1,978.8,994.6,1000.7,1012,1014.1,1017,1024.4,1025,1047.1,1068.3,1070.4,1080.6,1081.3,1081.8,1098.9,1100.7,1123.2,1132.2,1137.2,1143.4,1152.5,1155.8,1169.7,1173.5,1191.7,1219.1,1237.7,1243.5,1256.3,1281.7,1317.3,1322.6,1378,1383.5,1391.7,1401.6,1463.8,1465.5,1494.8,1534.6,1541.2,1546.5,1639.8,1722.5,1727.116,1876.9,1958.8,1992.7,2243.9,2379.1,2444.8,2457.1,2469.8,2681.8,3103,3164.5,3188.3,3341.9,3707.8,3961.5,3961.6,4627.1)

A <- c(0.9,1,0.67,0.93,0.45,0.55,0.87,0.8,1,0.68,0.71,0.47,0.67,1,0.79,0.71,0.85,0.9,0.84,0.43,0.59,0.54,0.49,0.49,0.58,0.36,0.56,0.7,0.5,0.43,0.54,0.37,0.38,0.33,0.38,0.51,0.51,0.3,0.44,0.48,0.51,0.46,0.3,0.42,0.31,0.51,0.41,0.22,0.34,0.32,0.41,0.46,0.29,0.44,0.38,0.5,0.26,0.34,0.41,0.27,0.23,0.4,0.44,0.4,0.45,0.36,0.22,0.41,0.32,0.35,0.34,0.5,0.36,0.33,0.28,0.35,0.33,0.26,0.31,0.38,0.37,0.28,0.27,0.38,0.39,0.28,0.35,0.36,0.29,0.31,0.3,0.3,0.34,0.19,0.29,0.27,0.24,0.3,0.3,0.27,0.28,0.27,0.24,0.25,0.3,0.27,0.32,0.25,0.26,0.37,0.32,0.28,0.27,0.29,0.28,0.28,0.26,0.33,0.29,0.22,0.27,0.16,0.24,0.23,0.19,0.3,0.21,0.25,0.26,0.25,0.24,0.27,0.24,0.3,0.27,0.23,0.26,0.23,0.26,0.27,0.24,0.2,0.21,0.16,0.26,0.25,0.18,0.27,0.21,0.18,0.22,0.2,0.24,0.19,0.24,0.23,0.23,0.19,0.18,0.24,0.21,0.25,0.21,0.19,0.23,0.22,0.18,0.13,0.16,0.16,0.24,0.19,0.15,0.21,0.2,0.17,0.15,0.16,0.14,0.18,0.14,0.16,0.18,0.16,0.17,0.13,0.18,0.15,0.15,0.18,0.21,0.2,0.13,0.13,0.16,0.16,0.15,0.16,0.12,0.16,0.2,0.17,0.16,0.11,0.13,0.12,0.13,0.12,0.19,0.12,0.13,0.1,0.11,0.12,0.1,0.15,0.09,0.09,0.12,0.11,0.11,0.11,0.11,0.04,0.06,0.05,0.03,0.03,0.03,0.02,0.02,0.03,0.03,0.03,0.02,0.02,0.02)

Data <- tibble(Leaf, A)
```

Now I have to emphasize that I have zero experience in modelling and I am only posting this question after nearly a couple of months of studying really hard on how to approach it. I understand that years and years go into this, so please excuse the naive questions.

Here are the steps I have taken to approach fitting a regression to this data:

1. Take a look at the plot of A vs Leaf length

```
Data %>% 
    ggplot(aes(Leaf, A)) + 
    geom_point()
```

[A versus Leaf length [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdlhn.png)]

The data clearly does not appear to linearly related so it would be pointless to attempt to fit it into a linear model. Both the x and y variables have a strong positive (right)  skew. I tried transforming the y variable using log and others as well followed by assessing the fit of the transformed data into a linear model using `gvlma::gvlma(formula)` but none of the transformations changed the original outcomes.

2. After reading several articles and stack links, I looked at the "form" of the scatter plot [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdlhn.png)] [[2](https://www.statforbiology.com/nonlinearregression/usefulequations#curve_shapes)] and observed that the data does likely show: inflection point, sigmoidal shape. Also, my y-axis data does go all the way to 1 while it does not necessarily touch 0. I can thus consider the following Concave/convex curves.
3. Based on another answer here, I used the following function from the `fitdistrplus` package to see the kind of distribution that my y-axis variable follows:

```
Data %>% 
    pull(A) %>% 
    fitdistrplus::descdist(.,boot = 10000)
```

It suggests something called the "beta distribution" and rules out normal, uniform, exponential, log-normal and gamma distribution. Regarding beta distribution, since my data consists of no 0s but some 1s, I need to check for the "1-inflated beta distribution".

4. Considering all of the above, I first fitted my data to the following models (includes some others that I thought to check based on some reading):

```
All_models <- list(
  Beta = gamlss::gamlss(A~pb(Leaf),
                        data = Data,
                        sigma.fo=~pb(Leaf), 
                        nu.fo=~pb(Leaf), 
                        family=BEINF1),
  DRC_LL.3u  =  drc::drm(A~Leaf,data = Data, fct = drc::LL.3u()),
  DRC_LL.4  =  drc::drm(A~Leaf,data = Data, fct = drc::LL.4()),
  DRC_LL.5  =  drc::drm(A~Leaf,data = Data, fct = drc::LL.5()),
  DRC_LL2.4  =  drc::drm(A~Leaf,data = Data, fct = drc::LL2.4()),
  DRC_LL2.5  =  drc::drm(A~Leaf,data = Data, fct = drc::LL2.5()),
  DRC_W1.3  =  drc::drm(A~Leaf,data = Data, fct = drc::W1.3()),
  DRC_W1.3u  =  drc::drm(A~Leaf,data = Data, fct = drc::W1.3u()),
  DRC_W1.4  =  drc::drm(A~Leaf,data = Data, fct = drc::W1.4()),
  DRC_W2.3  =  drc::drm(A~Leaf,data = Data, fct = drc::W2.3()),
  DRC_W2.3u  =  drc::drm(A~Leaf,data = Data, fct = drc::W2.3u()),
  DRC_W2.4  =  drc::drm(A~Leaf,data = Data, fct = drc::W2.4()),
  DRC_baro5  =  drc::drm(A~Leaf,data = Data, fct = drc::baro5()),
  DRC_G.3u  =  drc::drm(A~Leaf,data = Data, fct = drc::G.3u()),
  DRC_G.4  =  drc::drm(A~Leaf,data = Data, fct = drc::G.4()),
  DRC_MM.3  =  drc::drm(A~Leaf,data = Data, fct = drc::MM.3())
)
```

5. A look at the AIC of each of the models tells me that the 1-inflated beta regression turned out to be the best:

```
purrr::map2_df(
  .x = All_models,
  .y = names(All_models),
  ~{
    tibble(AIC = AIC(.x), 
           `Model type` = .y)
  }) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(AIC)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 2
     AIC `Model type`
   <dbl> <chr>       
 1 -706. Beta        
 2 -538. DRC_baro5   
 3 -538. DRC_LL2.4   
 4 -538. DRC_W2.4    
 5 -538. DRC_W2.3    
 6 -537. DRC_LL2.5   
 7 -537. DRC_LL.5    
 8 -537. DRC_LL.4    
 9 -532. DRC_MM.3    
10 -525. DRC_W2.3u   
11 -524. DRC_W1.4    
12 -510. DRC_W1.3    
13 -509. DRC_LL.3u   
14 -477. DRC_W1.3u   
15 -451. DRC_G.4     
16 -410. DRC_G.3u
```

This is how the beta-regression models my data:

```
Data %>% 
    ggplot(aes(Leaf, A)) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line(y =  predict(All_models[["Beta"]], type='response', se.fit=T) %>% 
                  purrr::pluck("fit"))
```

Output:

[image]

However when I look at the diagnostics of the plot:

```
All_models %>% 
    purrr::pluck("Beta") %>% 
    plot()
```

[image]

I see that the Q-Q plot shows that my sample quantiles don't exactly match up to the theoretical quantiles. There is some deviation there.

This tells me that I possibly have no considered some other better fitting model for my data: Can I get some help in figuring out which model best fits my data?

Comment: Is this a beta regression model ? If so then the residuals are not expected to be normally disttributed. You could look at the DHARMa package for this. Having said that, if you were looking for normallty distributed residuals - these plots look OK to me - the QQ plot is not perfect, but neither is it far from normal.

Comment: Thanks for your points. Do you think the way I've approached the problem is correct?